# Please help me understand the solution to this graph

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

I have a function

$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{0≤t<1} \\[2ex]
2, & \text{1≤t<2}
\end{cases}$$

According to the solutions manual, the period is 2

[image]
this is an odd function so I add $$-f(-t)$$

And get

$$f_o(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{0≤t<1} \\[2ex]
2, & \text{1≤t<2}  \\[2ex]
-2, & \text{-2≤t<-1}  \\[2ex]
0, & \text{-1≤t<0}
\end{cases}$$

I have trouble extending the graph. The period is 2, so initially I thought the graph of f(t) should repeat itself for every 2 units and the graph of -f(-t) should repeat itself for every 2pi, but thats not the case.

So if the function f(t) repeats itself every 2 units. The first period is from x=0 to x=2. And after x=2 the function should start again right?
For instance y=0 is between x=0 and 1, y=2 is between x= 1 and 2. If the function repeats itself after every two units, that means the function should continue after x=2 and we should get the new lines, y=0 between x=2 and 3, and y= 2 between x= 3 and 4. But looking at the solution, that clearly isnt the case.

[image]

Can someone please explain whats going on?

Edit:

Problem:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The function you have drawn has period 4. Were you told that it must have period 2? That's not compatible with having the form you describe and being an odd function.

Comment: Yes. I was told it has the period 2. I will update the post with the solution for T=2

Comment: OK. Were you also told it is an odd function? Or did you decide that it should be an odd function?

Comment: Honestly I understand 0 about this problem and this topic is my absolute weakness. I just checked the solutions manual hoping to understand how to solve it. And the solutions manual says Fourier-Sinus row is an odd function above the graph I posted here. Since the only way (that I know of at least) we can get those coordinates is by adding -f(-t) In those exact intervals. I decided its an odd function.

Comment: Could you scan in a copy of the question and a copy of the solutions manual? What language is it: Swedish?

Comment: I have added in a copy of the question and solutions manual. If anyone is interested. I would gladly pay to be tutored a couple hours in this topic. I understand nothing, and the book doesn't do a good job covering this topic. It doenst seem complicated at all, its just that I cant find any helpful information anywhere.

Comment: The language is Norwegian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the extra information.

a) You are asked to determine the period and the frequency. Based on the information you are given, the best choice is a period of 2.

The graph with period 2 should look like this:

[image]

b) You are asked to express the function f as a Fourier Sine Series. Because the sine function is an odd function, we pretend that your function is also odd!

Rotating your initial function about the origin gives us:
[image]

Taking this element and repeating it gives us the periodic function with period $T=4$ as plotted in the solutions manual.

Comment: This http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSineSeries.aspx might help.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you are given on the function are inconsistent.  If you are told the function is odd and period $2$ you should only specify it over a range of $1$, such as $[0,1]$. You can use the fact that it is odd to extend that to $[-1,1]$, then use the fact that it is period $2$ to extend it over the whole real line.  Alternately, you are given the values over $[0,2)$.  You can extend it as period $2$, but it will not be odd.  You can extend it to be odd, giving values over $(-2,2)$, and then extend it as a period $4$ function (though you will not have values for $2+4k$ if you do this.